# how to solveBuild failed with an exception in flutter?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-engine

Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help

Comment: Did you already tried what the error suggests? `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights` . Would be helpful to have more logs. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

try flutter clean
than run the app if still not working try running with android studio if you are using vs code